# resources for embedded projects

Tags: c++, embedded

Can anyone suggest links/resources for sample project implementations of embedded projects using c++ or gcc.

Comment: I strongly suggest that you expand on this question as suggested in the answers thus far before it gets more votes to close.

Comment: C++ is a language, gcc is a compiler (supporting C and C++).  Is it the language or the compiler you are interested in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many resources are target specific, so you will have to be more specific if you want a specific answer.  However http://embedded.com/ is a good general resource, and depending on your geographical location, you may qualify for a free subscription to *Embedded Systems Design* or *Embedded Systems Design Europe* paper publications.

Apart from Atmel AVR, GCC is targetted for 16/32bit targets, and C++ is generally ambitious and unnecessary for 8 bit, so I am guessing we are considering 16/32bit targets?

You might also take a look at:

- [Martin Thomas's ARM-Projects](http://www.siwawi.arubi.uni-kl.de/avr_projects/arm_projects/), including a GCC toolchain for Windows.
- http://embdev.net/ which includes an embedded GCC forum.
- [Building Bare-Metal ARM Systems with GNU](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.state-machine.com%2Farm%2FBuilding_bare-metal_ARM_with_GNU.pdf&ei=jPoRTI3oK4z80wSm77HxAg&usg=AFQjCNFTVcfMnC2OCPJd8KXtLT7ZQlm_GA&sig2=vzP5nyUr-bdM96OMyaxr4g) A description of bringing up a system using GCC with C *and* C++
- [FreeRTOS](http://www.freertos.org/) a well respected and widely used open-source RTOS kernel
- [eCos](http://ecos.sourceware.org/) another open-source RTOS, but somewhat more than a scheduler kernel.

Answer (score 1):

There are many many many resources....the question is too broad.  Do you have a particular embedded micro you are targetting?

different embedded apps have different concerns

- real time concerns?
- extremely limited memory / resources?
- OS? no OS?
- Security?
- Failsafe?
- Device Drivers?

Comment: I think I require resources for real time systems.

Answer (score 0):

Question is incomplete, you have to provide all information, like product summary, hardware you want to use. But I guess you are porting some linux kernel to some embedded device.

For application program, easiest is to cross compile your code from your local system for specific arch and then transfer the binary to your embedded product.